# tabindex: unable to focus elements that are visible only on hover

Tags: html, hover, onfocus, lost-focus, keyboard-navigation

I have a list of items(`ul`, `li` elements), where `li` contains left content and right content.for each `li` tabindex is set to 0.

By default left content is always visible, When user mouse hovers on each of the `li`, i am toggling visiblity of right content.

right content has three action icons all with tabindex set to 0.

The issue is when i am using keyboard TAB key to gain focus on each `li`, i am able to see the action icons in the right panel, but immediately pressing TAB key,i am losing the focus on `li` element, so the right action panel becomes invisible and not able to access elements inside `li` right panel using keyboard.

Requirement:

When i am focusing on a particular `li`, immediately pressing TAB key should select the action icons(which are visible only when there is focus on `li` element) inside the `li`, instead of skipping action icons as the action icons also have tabindex set to 0.

Below is the sample code snippet for reference

```
<ul>
<li tabindex="0">
    <div class="left-content">
        <label>{{cartList.item_name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
        <div class="actionsBar">
            <span class="descriptionIcon" tabindex="0"></span>
            <span class="deleteIcon" tabindex="0"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>


<style type = "text/css"> 
         li:hover, li:focus  {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #cccccc;
            color: #333333;
         }
         .right-content {
            visibility: hidden;
         }

        .right-content:hover, .right-content:focus  {
            visibility: visible;
        }
</style>
```

The right-content will be visible only on hover of `li` tag

Thanks in Advance.